# Remove the connection bar from Hyper-V connection

Tags: remote-desktop, hyper-v

When connecting to remote or virtual machines through RDP in full screen, a blue connection bar is usually shown in the top of the screen.

[image: Connection bar]

I want to remove this connection bar from a Hyper-V connection (not just "unpinning", but removing it entirely).

When I access remote servers through RDP I can choose to remove the connection bar entirely from the connection settings before connecting:

[image: RDP connection settings]

However, when I connect to a Hyper-V virtual machine, that setting (amongst others) is not shown:

[image: Hyper V connection settings]

How do I remove the connection bar from a connection to a virtual Hyper-V machine?

Comment: I actually had the exact opposite problem once - my bar had disappeared and I couldn't get it back! To get it back I had to restart the host, I couldn't find any specific setting  for it.

Answer (score 3):

If your VM is on the same LAN as your client then you can connect to your VM using the standard Remote Desktop Connection and disable it there, as you would for any remote server.

You will need to allow remote connections on the guest OS on the VM.

An example in Windows 10:

`Windows Explorer` -> Right-click on `This PC` -> `Properties` -> `Advanced system settings` -> `Remote` -> `Allow remote connections to this computer`

[image]